# Why declaring Urls instead of arbitrary string in XSD Namespaces?

Tags: xml, xsd

Why declaring Urls(http://ebay.in/data/typee) instead of arbitrary string(ebay.in.data.types) in XSD Namespaces?.Is it required valid url as namespace?

Answer (score 0):

The namespaces specification is a bit ambivalent about this. It says that it must be a URI (or IRI in namespaces 1.1), but it also says that parsers should not reject the document it it isn't a URI. Oddly, although it is permissive about using a string that isn't a URI, it's very keen to deprecate using a relative URI (such as 'blablabla').

There are other specs in the XML family that are stricter about requiring the namespace to be a URI (for example XML canonicalization), and there are also some products (notably XOM) that enforce this restriction. So it's best to swim with the tide and use legal URIs for your namespaces.

Incidentally, the spec says URI not URL. There are other kinds of URI, for example URNs. Microsoft in particular are quite keen on using URNs as namespaces. One advantage is that they don't look like references to web pages, so people don't imagine that the parser is going to fetch anything from the web.